# Is there a way to search a cell for specific words--regardless of order?

Tags: excel

Basically, I'm trying to write a function that will search for a phrase like "good job" and return cells including those words in any order--whether it's "he had a good job" "is this job good" or "good work on your last job."

I've tried a search and index/match approaches. Either will return the first example, but neither returns the second two.

Is there a function that will do this? Thanks!

Comment: you would need vba

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"good","job"},A1)))=2
```

will return TRUE if both words are present

[image]

To use this method with the two search words in a single cell is possible, but requires some complexity to turn the two words into an array.  If the two search words are in A1, then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:2"))-1)*98+1,99)),B1)))=2
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution--as it's more compact. But, I'd like the formula to inherit the search terms from a single cell (rather than inputting them manually). Is that possible using this formula? Here's a picture of the result for which I'm looking: https://imgur.com/a/6FbE4

Comment: Yes you can.  It involves making the two words into an array.  I will edit my post

Comment: This is helpful. If I have other cells with more than two words for which I'm looking (like "good job for graduating seniors" instead of "good job,") is there a formula that can expand to include more words?

Comment: You could replace the `2` in  `"1:2"` and in `=2` to reflect the # of words you want to check, and how many need to be present.  And this could be calculated by an embedded function in your formula.  However, if you are going to use words that might also be found in other words, (eg `a`, `for`, etc) a VBA solution would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Say your formula is in cell A2 and your text string is in A1

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(FIND("GOOD",UPPER(A1))>0,FIND("JOB",UPPER(A1))>0),A1,),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible with Conditional Formatting (though nowhere near as flexible as VBA):

[image: SO46143700 example]

The above using the CF formula rule applied to ColumnB (`good job` in A1) of:

```
=FIND(LEFT($A$1,FIND(" ",$A$1)-1),B1)+FIND(MID($A$1,FIND(" ",$A$1)+1,LEN($A$1)),B1)
```

---

To report TRUE or FALSE instead maybe:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(LEFT($A$1,FIND(" ",$A$1)-1),B1)+FIND(MID($A$1,FIND(" ",$A$1)+1,LEN($A$1)),B1)>0,FALSE)
```