# I am trying to get a result to display '0' to show no credit will be given

Tags: excel-formula

My name is Robert, and I am an intermediate school math teacher. The following formula works for me, but I also need to a assign a value of zero for a response not meeting the full or partial credit criteria. Any assistance you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

=IF(B1="","",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("minimum",B1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("maximum",B1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("range",B1)),NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"mean","median","mean absolute deviation","interquartile range"},B1)))),2,1))

Student Response:

The minimum would most likely stay the same because unless the hit was less than 10 then it shouldnt change. Its the same with the maximum. Unless his hit is higher than 50 then it shouldnt change either. All of the other things would change because a new number was added in. The mean would change.The median would change. The mean absolute deviation would change. The would change. And finally, the interequality would change as well.

(Full Credit):

If a cell contains "minimum", "maximum", and "range" with any other words EXCLUDING "mean", "median", "mean absolute deviation", or "interquartile range", I want to assign the result to a value of '2'.

(Partial Credit):

If a cell contains "minimum", "maximum", and range" with any other words INCLUDING "mean", "median", "mean absolute deviation", or "interquartile range", I want to assign the result to a value of '1'.

(Zero Credit):

If a cell DOES NOT contain "minimum", "maximum", and "range" with any other words EXCLUDING "mean", "median", "mean absolute deviation", or "interquartile range", I want to assign the result to a value of '0'.

OR

If a cell DOES NOT contain "minimum", "maximum", and "range" with any other words INCLUDING "mean", "median", "mean absolute deviation", or "interquartile range", I want to assign the result to a value of '0'.

Answer (score 0):

use this thread - it has something similar using true/false for certain words in a string. [Is there a way to search a cell for specific words--regardless of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143700/is-there-a-way-to-search-a-cell-for-specific-words-regardless-of-order)